# Calculator app using jsf append issue

Tags: java, jsf

i made this calculator program using jsf and a class
i used command buttons to pass and append numbers (like a pocket calculator not first number second number sort of calculator) here is the sample of the code i have a problem with

i want entered values to be appended so for example CLICKING 1 three times gives 111

here the enteredvalue shows as one while the appendedvalue is always the same (1) i have 
@ApplicationScoped in the class

```
<h:inputText value="#{mbcalculator.result}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="1" action="#{mbcalculator.setNumber}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{mbcalculator.enteredvalue}"
            value="1" />


       //mbcalculator class

    public String setNumber() {
    appendNumber(enteredvalue);

    return null;
}

public void appendNumber(String x) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(x + "");
    String str = buffer.toString();
    appendedvalue = Integer.parseInt(str);
            result = appendedvalue;


    System.out.println("enter"+enteredvalue);
    System.out.println("append"+appendedvalue);
    System.out.println("result"+result);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate "does nothing" in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. Is the HTTP request been sent? Which phases of JSF lifecycle are invoked? Is the setter invoked? Is the action method invoked? Etc.

Comment: also, add some logging or error if you have any

Comment: Did you use `debugging` or a `system.out` to check whether `doEquals()` method executes.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for the prompt response. i added syso and i saw that the append method is not appending it is simply giving me one. when what i really want is 1 to be appened each time so for example clicking 1 three times would give u appendedvalue 111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `appendNumber()` you're overriding the whole `result` instead of appending to it.

```
result = appendedvalue;
```

Fix it accordingly by really appending to the `result`.

```
public void appendNumber(String x) {
    result = Integer.parseInt(result + x);
}
```

Comment: thank you this worked for me looks like i didn't need the string buffer